# Core app logging requests but not traces to app insights

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights

I noticed that my .net core app is logging requests, but not traces to my azure app insights.

I'm setting up app insights in my **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
            {
                options.InstrumentationKey = Configuration["ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey"];
            });
```

I'm injecting ILogger in my controller like such

```
private readonly ILogger<HealthCheckController> _logger;

public HealthCheckController(ILogger<HealthCheckController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult HealthCheck()
{
    // Custom EventId for logging
    var eventId = EventDefinition.TestMicroservice.HealthCheckController.HealthCheck;

    _logger.LogInformation(eventId, "Test Microservice health check successful.");

    return Ok("Test Microservice is running!");
}
```

Am I missing something?  I've hit my controller multiple times and I'm seeing requests getting logged, but my custom log messages are nowhere to be found under traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I found was that I was able to inject **TelemetryClient** despite wanting to use **ILogger**.  While I kept the above code in, I had to add the **.ConfigureLogging**

```
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                    new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                    {
                        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                        return new WebHostBuilder()
                                    .UseKestrel()
                                    .ConfigureServices(
                                        services => services
                                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                                    {
                                        var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
                                        
                                        // Add Key Vault
                                        var kv = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections[KeyVaultOptions.Position].Parameters;                                        
                                        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(kv["TenantId"].Value, kv["ClientId"].Value, kv["ClientSecret"].Value);
                                        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kv["Url"].Value), credential);

                                        config.AddAzureKeyVault(client, new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions());
                                        config.Build();
                                    })
                                    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
                                    {
                                        logging.AddApplicationInsights(
                                            context.Configuration["ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey"]);
                                        logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);
                                    })
                                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                    .UseUrls(url)
                                    .Build();
                    }))
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, only Warning or higher is collected by ApplicationInsights. You can change it following the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#how-do-i-customize-ilogger-logs-collection